# why does my program work with numbers greater than one

Tags: python

I'm doing my own thing just for fun, and I decided to try to make a program find the fraction of a reoccurring decimal. I have tried this program quite a bit and got it to always work until we reach numbers that are greater than 1

```py
whole = number // 1
number -= whole
repeating = ''
final_repeating = ''
copy_of_number = str(number)
stop = False

number = str(number)[2:]
for digit in number:
    repeating += digit
    number = number[1:]
    for checker in range(len(repeating)):
        try:
            if repeating[checker] == number[0]:
                final_repeating = repeating[checker:]
                times_it_appears = number.count(final_repeating)
                length = len(number)
                length_of_final = len(final_repeating)
                if times_it_appears == length // length_of_final and (length % length_of_final == 0 or number[(length % length_of_final * -1):] == final_repeating[:(length % length_of_final)]):
                    stop = True
                    break
                else:
                    final_repeating = ''
        except IndexError:
            print('this isn\'t a reoccuring decimal')
            quit()
    if stop == True:
        break
```

If number = 1.166666 or any other amount of 6's that is >= 2, then it final_repeating should equal '6' and the code should move on

The actual output is that it isn't a reoccurring decimal, and if I check number. after the program finishes, there are a lot of 0's and some random single number at the end a user doesn't type in

Comment: sorry about the bad variable names and long if statement. I'm an intermediate programmer

Comment: how do you get the variable number ?

Comment: sorry. that is user input.

Comment: In `if stop == True:`, writing `if stop:` is sufficient.

Comment: my programming teacher said that though it may work, it is more pythonic to write out the entire thing. I prefer writing out the entire thing myself. It is just my preference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract whole from number, Python approximates the result. You can round the number when subtracting whole from number to avoid this.

Replace the first two lines of your code with this:

```py
copy_of_number=str(number)
whole = int(number // 1)
copy_of_whole=str(whole)
number -= whole
number = round(number, len(copy_of_number)-len(copy_of_whole)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a program  that converts "any" given rational number into a fraction using a function that receives a string representing a rational number such as `"2.5(37)"`, `"-7.8"` or `"4"`  and returns a string with the correspondent fraction.

Eg.: `from_string_to_fraction("-2.5(37)")` returns `"-1256/495"`. It needs the functions `gcd()` and `number_of_decimal_places_of()`.

This only works with [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) because rational numbers are all the numbers and the only numbers that can be written as the divison of two integers, that's the definition of ratinal numbers. Note that [recurring decimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) ([dízimas infinitas periódicas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADzima_peri%C3%B3dica)) are rational numbers, and that [0,(9)=1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...).

```py
"""
Author: @t3m2.
Date of creation: 09/07/2019, , dd/mm/yyyy, (july).
Version: 14/12/2019, dd/mm/yyyy, (december).
Language: Python.

This program defines three functions which can be used to
converts rational numbers into fractions:
from_string_to_fraction(),
gcd() and number_of_decimal_places_of().

I have built the function from_string_to_fraction()
that receives a string representing a rational number
in decimal notation (including repeating decimals),
such as "2.5(37)", "-7.8" or "4"
and returns a string with the correspondent fraction
in form "n/m" where n and m are integers.

Eg.: from_string_to_fraction("-2.5(37)") returns "-1256/495". 

If the number is a repeating decimal,
its peridod should appear between round brackets.

It needs the functions gcd() and number_of_decimal_places_of()!

Read the functions' docstrings for more information.
"""
__author__ = "t3m2"
__date__ = "09/07/2019, , dd/mm/yyyy, (july)"
__version__ = "14/12/2019, dd/mm/yyyy, (december)"


def gcd(a=1, b=1):
  """Returns the greatest common divisor
  between two positive integers. 
  (Recursive solution)

  Make sure a and b are positive int's 
  because this function assumes that."""
  if b == 0:
    return a 
  else: 
    return gcd(b, a%b)


def number_of_decimal_places_of(x=0):
  """Returns the number of decimal places of a float or int.

  Make sure x is a float or int
  because this function assumes that."""
  if x == int(x):
    return 0
  return len(str(x)[str(x).index('.')+1:])


def from_string_to_fraction(x='0'):
  """Receives a string representing a rational number in decimal notation,
  (including repeating decimals) such as "-2.5(37)", "-7.8" or "4", and
  returns a string with the correspondent fraction in form "n/m",
  where both n and m are integers. 

  Eg.: from_string_to_fraction("-2.5(37)") returns "-1256/495".

  It needs the functions gcd() and number_of_decimal_places_of()!

  This only works with rational numbers because rational numbers
  are all the numbers and the only numbers that can be written as
  the divison of two integers, that's the definition of rational numbers.
  Note that recurring decimals are rational numbers, and that 0,(9)=1.

  Make sure that: (input restrictions)
  - the argument is a valid string representing
    a rational number in decimal notation;
  - the decimal separator (if there) is a '.' or a ',';
  - if the input is a recurring decimal, the period comes between round brackets.
    (12.431111111111111... is represented as "12.43(1)".)
  Because this function assumes that!"""

  # The input string can have a ',' or a '.' separating the int and the decimal part:
  x = x.replace(',', '.', 1)  

  sign = 1 
  if x[0] == '-':  
    # iff x represent a negative number, this turns x into
    # a string representing positive number,
    # because if it easier to work with positives numbers.
    # And, in the end, we turn the result into negative again
    # by making something like: "final_result*=sign".
    sign = -1
    x = x[1:]

  ### Getting the finit part (f) and the period (p): ###

  # I will explain this with an example:
  # If x == "2.5(37)"; then I set f, the finit part, to 2.5 and p, the period, to 37.
  # If the number is non-recurring, f = x, since it has no period.
  # Eg: if x == "-3.4"; then f = -3.4 and p = 0.
  # Note that x, our argument, is still a 'string'.

  try:  # This will be executed iff x is a non-recurring decimal:
    f = eval(x)  # eval(x) "turns" the string x into a float or int.
    p = 0
  except TypeError:  # This will be executed iff x is a recurring decimal:
    f = float(x[:x.index('(')])  # The finit part of the dizim is all the way until '('.

    p = int(x[x.index('(')+1:x.index(')')])  # The period of the dizim is 
    # the part of the number between '(' and ')').

  ### Getting the numerator and denominator: ###

  # With f and p defined, I have to discover the numerator and the denominator:

  # Here is a method that can be used in order to discover the fraction:
  # If y=2,5(37): (mathematical notation)
  # 1000y - 10y = 2537,(37) - 25,(37)     <=>
  # 1000y - 10y = 2537 - 25               <=>
  # (1000-10) * y = 2537 - 25             <=>
  # <=> y = (2537-25)  /   (1000-10)      <=>
  # <=> y =  2512      /     990           =>
  #  => y = numerator  /    denominator    => # Then we need to simplify the fraction,
  #  => y =  1256      /     495              # and this will be the final result.

  # Note that both numerator and denominator are integers.
  # I implemented this with f and p:

  numerator = f*10**(number_of_decimal_places_of(f)+len(str(p)))+p \
              - f*10**number_of_decimal_places_of(f) 

  denominator = 10**(number_of_decimal_places_of(f)+len(str(p))) \
                - 10**number_of_decimal_places_of(f)

  ### Simplifying the fraction: ###

  # Here I am slimplifying the fraction, if it's possible:

  factor = gcd(numerator, denominator)

  # "sign*" is used to get the correct sign of the final answer, 
  # ie, the same sign of x.
  numerator = sign*(numerator/factor)
  denominator = denominator/factor

  return "%d/%d" % (numerator, denominator)


### TESTING ###

print("This program turns \"any\" rational number in decimal notation \
into a fraction, for example: -2.5(37) = -2.537373737373737... = -1256/495\n\n")

while 1:
  try:
    x = input("Enter a rational number in decimal notation (exit: 'b'): ")
    if x == 'b':
      break
    print("%s = %s" % (x, from_string_to_fraction(x)))
  except:
    print("Error: probably, invalid input.")

  print()
```

If it doesn't help, I am sorry, but it will probably help others in the future.

This answer took me lots of time, I hope that someone in the future will use this to convert rational numbers in tithe notation to fractions.

The program seems to be a little bit big but this is due to the comments.

[Repository of this program in GitHub.](https://github.com/t3m2/Converting-rational-numbers-in-decimal-notation-to-fractions)

[Working on Repl.it.](https://repl.it/github/t3m2/Converting-rational-numbers-in-decimal-notation-to-fractions)

Comment: sorry. This is a bit late, but I understand from the beginning to the try and except where you define f and p.

I don't see where you define p in the try, and the print statement at the end. I don't know what the '"%s = %s " %' means

Comment: `p` is defined in the beginning of the function: `p=0 # set the period of the number to 0`. [Lost of explainations of the "%s=%s"%(a,b)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%25s%22+%25+string+python&rlz=1C1GCEV_en&oq=%22%25s%22+%25+string+python&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6805j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), each `%s` is "replaced" by the respective string that comes after; or by an `int` in case of `%d`; or by a `float` in case of `%f`.  Basically: `"%d/%d" % (numerator,denominator)" == str(numerator) + '/' + str(denominator)`

Comment: `%s` is used for string formatting. `"%s = %s" % (x,from_string_to_fraction(x)) == x + " = " + from_string_to_fraction(x)`

Comment: Now `p` is defined in the `try` block.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. I'll look into this as it is probably a lot more efficient than mine and looks 100x better. I understand the string formatting now (I just tested it inside a shell)